# Question on this extension of abelian topological groups

Tags: topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

A question on abelian topological groups:

Let $G$ be an abelian topological (Hausdorff) group and let $N$ be a closed subgroup of $G$. Assume that $N$ is (as a topological group) isomorphic to $(\mathbb R,+)$ and that $G/N$ is (as a topological group) isomorphic to $(\mathbb R^\omega,+)$. (the countable product of copies of $\mathbb R$)

Does this imply that $G$ is isomorhic (as a topological group) to $(\mathbb R^\omega,+)$ ?